# Create Random Number with 16 Digits (JAVA)

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to create randomally number with 16 digits in java.
I can do it with String and after that convert to Long.
there is other option?

Thanks!

Comment: It is considered helpful, if the topic starter accepts one of the answers, if they helped.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the Java class Random to generate random Longs, like here for numbers up to one million:

```
final long MAX_NUMBER_YOU_WANT_TO_HAVE = 9999999999999999L;
final long MIN_NUMBER_YOU_WANT_TO_HAVE = 1000000000000000L;
Long actual = Long.valueOf(Math.abs(Float.valueOf(new Random().nextFloat() * (MAX_NUMBER_YOU_WANT_TO_HAVE - MIN_NUMBER_YOU_WANT_TO_HAVE)).longValue()));
```

Comment: thanks, but when i enter the number :9999999999999999 (16digits)
i got error: the literal of 9999999999999999 of type int is out of range

Comment: Use a long not an int, like I did in my answer. Look at the constant for the variable.

Comment: @user2097810 Try `9999999999999999L`.

Comment: This code seems to be wrong. It returns negative values that are obviously smaller than `MIN_NUMBER_YOU_WANT_TO_HAVE`, or values that are much bigger than `MAX_NUMBER_YOU_WANT_TO_HAVE`.

Answer (score 4):

If you absolutely need 16 digits (not a number from 0 to 10^17-1)

```
Random rand = new Random;
long accumulator = 1 + rand.nextInt(9); // ensures that the 16th digit isn't 0
for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    accumulator *= 10L;
    accumulator += rand.nextint(10);
}
```

I might have an off-by-one on the for loop, use `i < 16` if need be.

Answer (score 2):

Your reason for wanting 16 digits is probably key here.

If you only want a number possibly as big as the biggest 16-digit number, then use your favored random number generator to generate a random number between `0` and `9 999 999 999 999 999`. You can then add leading zeroes as needed to display exactly 16 characters if that's the reason.

If you explicitly want there to be 16 decimal digits and the first one cannot be zero, you can try the same exercise with `999 999 999 999 999` as upper bound instead and add a random digit from 1 to 9 in front (multiply it by a quadrillion and then sum with the other random number, if need be).

There's plenty of other options, but those are probably the most obvious and simple to implement. I'm quite sure there are native facilities in Java for generating random long numbers.